# Accessing the node details in the selected contextmenu - D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How to set the node attributes in the context menu so that when an option is selected by clicking that node, I can access the node (`id`) and the selected option.

I want to call an action that takes 2 parameters - the node id and the option selected.

The datum passed in the `click` function is only the selected option value.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aa1024/qhj3tgs8/)

```
    d3.select('svg')
        .append('g').attr('class', 'context-menu') .selectAll('tmp')
        .data(items).enter() .append('g').attr('class', 'menu-entry')
        .style({'cursor': 'pointer'})
        .on('mouseover', function(){ 
            d3.select(this).select('rect').style(style.rect.mouseover) })
        .on('mouseout', function(){ 
            d3.select(this).select('rect').style(style.rect.mouseout) })
        .on('click',  function(d) { 
           //callSomeAction('node.id','selected option')
          console.log(d); return d; 
        });
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you should be able to use `console.log(n);`, next to `console.log(d);` where `n` refers to the `d.id` used when instantiating the menu `menu(d.id, d3.mouse(svg.node())[0],...`

Comment: Thanks @XavierGuihot, I completely missed the fact that the `n` can be accessed from anywhere in the context.